# Passing 'currently selected row' to new view controller (kinda works - lags 1 behind)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

What I'm trying to do is pass the currently selected row in a UITableView to another view controller that's also a UITabelView. It works (kind of) but my variables are playing leapfrog with each other (seem to be 1 off for some reason.)

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    chosenProject = [[self activeProjectsList] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    self.selectedProject = chosenProject;
    [self setSelectedProject:self.selectedProject]; 
    NSLog(@"PROJECT: %@",chosenProject); // Returns correctly.

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowShots"]) {

    NSLog(@"CURRENT: %@",chosenProject); // Returns NULL?

    ShotListViewController *slVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    slVC.outputName = self.selectedProject;

    }
}
```

It's strange because the first time it will return NULL, then when you try again it returns the last selected row that should have been presented the first time.. not NULL.

I'm guessing that the variable is not being set before prepareForSegue is sent which is why it seems to be always one behind when it receives.

Am I going about this wrong, just to pass one variable?

Comment: Are you alloc'ing and init'ing the var that holds your value in the new viewController first, or when it is set by the first view?

Comment: Also, note that `[self setSelectedProject:self.selectedProject];` is setting selectedProject to itself, so does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.  `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called **after** the row is selected and after the segue is called.

You need to put this code in `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead, so that it is called before the segue is done.

Comment: Oh good grief.. how did I miss that! Works just like it should, thanks!